# Help with Max power

Tags: power-supply

I am wanting to buy a wifi enabled outlet to plug our AC unit into. I am getting confused with the specs, and was hoping someone can help us.

On the AC website it says:

Maximum power consumption: 1250 W / 10.8 A . Power supply: 115 V / 60Hz / 1

For the outlet it says:

Max Power: 2200W for 220V, 1100W for 110V

Not sure why there are two sets of wattage?

I looked at another and it said this:

Input voltage : 110V- 240V
Input frequency: 50Hz / 60Hz
Operating Load: 10A
Maximum Power: 2KW

So would these be compatible?

Comment: Both power consumption and current draw for the AC must be less than the maximum that the outlet can provide, is that the case? The reason there are two different ratings for two different voltages is because it is limited by current, 10 A specifically, as power = voltage * current.

Answer (score 1):

Both outlets are limited to 10A, regardless of voltage. Since power = voltage × current, that's why the first one shows different power levels for different voltages.

I assume that "AC" stands for "air conditioner" here. In that case, there are other considerations. The compressor motor typically has a huge start-up surge that is not reflected in the maximum average power rating. Depending on exactly what switching technology your WiFi outlet uses, this surge could easily destroy it.

One suggestion would be to get an industrial contactor that is specifically rated for motor loads in that power range, and use the Wifi outlet to switch that.